# jython open image from online

Tags: python, jython, urllib, urlopen, jes

For my Python college class I am trying to open an image from online to add to another image (using Jython). My code so far is:

```
def addLogo(lgPic):
  import urllib
  logo = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png")
  targetX = getWidth(lgPic) - getWidth(logo)
  targetY = getHeight(lgPic) - getHeight(logo)
  for x in range(0, getWidth(logo)):
    for y in range(0, getHeight(logo)):
      pix = getPixel(logo, x, y)
      bPix = getPixel(lgPic, x + targetX, y + targetY)
      color = getColor(pix)
      bColor = getColor(bPix)
      if distance(color, Color(0, 215, 0)) > 50:
        newPix = getPixel(lgPic, x + targetX, y + targetY)
        setColor(bPix, color)
  return lgPic
```

This returns the error:

> getWidth(picture): Input is not a picture
>       The error was:
>       Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
>       An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

How can I simply bring this image in and work with it?

Comment: I also tried 'logo = makePicture(urllib.urlopen("http://www.wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png"))'

Comment: Where is `getWidth` defined?

Comment: getWidth() is part of Jython. It works if I open an image from the HDD, but I can't figure out how to use an online image the same way.

Comment: What about `logo = makePicture("http://www.wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png")`

Comment: That returns:
makePicture(filename): There is no file at C:\Program Files (x86)\JES 4.3\http://www.wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png
The error was:
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

Comment: Can you save the file to your local system and reference it from there?

Comment: You can use `urllib.urlretrieve` to save the file locally and pass the local file to `makePicture`.

Comment: I tried
`urllib.urlretrieve('http://wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png', 'logo.png')`

I got:
`     The error was:File not found - logo.png (Access is denied)
     I/O operation failed.
     I tried to read a file, and couldn't.  Are you sure that file exists? If it does exist, did you specify the correct directory/folder?`

It seems to be a Windows permission problem. Also this may be run on a Mac, so don't want to use absolute paths.

Comment: Use the full url. Including the `http://` part.

Comment: I did - `urllib.urlretrieve('http://wsiab.net/BITsoft/Lab7/csumb-logo-white.png', 'logo.png')`